# Can not call global function from php class

Tags: php, functional-programming

I have a php project that uses some functional elements, and some OOP elements, but it seems mixing the two is causing problems. Here are the files that are causing the errors:

**DB.php**

```
<?php

function parse_db_entry($from, &$to){
    //Function code here
}

?>
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'DB.php';

class User{

    //Properties

    public function __construct(){
        //ctor
    }

    public static function load_user($email, $password){

        $entry = //Make MySQL Request
        $user = new User();

        parse_db_entry($entry, $user);

        return $user;

    }
}

?>
```

Everything works as it should, except the call to `parse_db_entry` which throws:

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function parse_db_entry()

I am able to access other things in **DB.php**, for instance if I made a class it there I am able to instantiate it without error, and if I move the function into **User.php**, it is functional as well. So what am I doing wrong? Why can't I call this method?

Comment: I am pretty sure `DB.php` not is named `DB.php`, _or_ is located in a subfolder, like `functions/DB.php` or similar.

Comment: @davidkonrad If that were the case, then `require_once` would throw an error.

Comment: Both `DB.php` and `User.php` are in the same folder **php**, and the User class is being accessed from a file one directory higher, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I set it up as above, because I couldnt believe it :) Two files. I can call `parse_db_entry` from within the static class function, so there must be something else going on ..

Comment: @davidkonrad I agree. Something *unnatural* is going on here.

Comment: @tVoss double check your script.. maybe you renamed DB.php

Comment: As I said, I am accessing the user object from a php file that is one directory higher than these to files. I found that if I include `DB.php` in this higher file, everything worked fine, but this seems rather hacky to me.

Comment: @tVoss, then it may be `require_once 'php/DB.php';`

Comment: That works in the higher file, but not in `User.php`. I could just require `DB.php` from the outside, but I'd like to keep it contained in `User.php` if possible.

Comment: Try `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);` before require_once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out! Thanks to everyone who had ideas, but it seems the problem was something else.

When calling `require_once 'DB.php'`, php was actually getting the file:

**C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php**

instead of mine.

This may be a problem exclusive to XAMPP, but a simple rename of my file to `DBUtil.php` fixed everything.

Comment: Could this be due to PHP's `include_path` directive? My XAMPP installation has the value of `.;C:\dev\xampp\php\PEAR`: the directory of the calling file would be looked at first, then PEAR. What does yours say? `echo ini_get('include_path');`

Answer (score 0):

This is a stretch, and I'm totally taking a shot in the dark here, but...

Are you sure `parse_db_entry` is in the global or User's namespace?
Note: I added a few lines here and there for testing/debugging.

DB.php:

```
<?php

namespace anotherWorld; // added this ns for illustrative purposes

function parse_db_entry($from, &$to){
    echo 'called it';
}

?>
```

User.php:

```
<?php

namespace helloWorld; // added this ns for illustrative purposes

class User {
    //Properties
    public function __construct(){
        //ctor
    }
    public static function load_user($email, $password){
        $entry = //Make MySQL Request
        $user = new User();
        parse_db_entry($entry, $user);
        return $user;
    }
}

?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'DB.php';
require_once 'User.php';

use helloWorld\User;

$a = new User();
$a->load_user('email','pass');
echo 'complete';

?>
```

Yields `Fatal error: Call to undefined function helloWorld\parse_db_entry() in User.php on line 13`, however when removing the NS declaration in DB.php (`namespace anotherWorld`) thereby putting `parse_db_entry` in global NS it runs just fine.

To verify, use the [`__NAMESPACE__` constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php).

---

If namespace is a problem, without compromising DB's namespace, here is an updated User.php:

```
<?php

namespace helloWorld;

use anotherWorld; // bring in the other NS

class User {
    //Properties
    public function __construct(){
        //ctor
    }
    public static function load_user($email, $password){
        $entry = //Make MySQL Request
        $user = new User();
        anotherWorld\parse_db_entry($entry, $user); // call the method from that NS
        return $user;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I feel this is close, but it's still a file location issue. Could you retry what you've done, but put DB.php and User.php in a subfolder, which is how I have my files laid out, due to how wordpress works.

Comment: @tVoss OK, I *just* did as you asked and it didn't make a bit of difference. As crush said above, if the file wasn't found require_once would throw a fatal error (E_FATAL, etc.) and if it was found, then without a doubt parse_db_entry would be available. I assure you, it is not an issue with file structure.

Comment: Then could it be an issue with wordpress? I can't seem to think of any other explanation.

Comment: @tVoss, most likely not, my money is on an implementation oversight.

Comment: Figured it out, it was a naming conflict. See my answer for details.